# Создавать отдельные модули или просто писать все в один файл. Правильность написания или нужен ли рефакторинг

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Вопрос по сути не сложный. Суть его такова как будет лучше писать код создавать отдельные модули ( файлы с кусками основного кода ) или просто писать все в один файл, но с комментариями. Пример ниже:

1. file1.py

   ```
   import l
   def iii():
     radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection = l.QRadioButton('Мальчик', l.root)
     radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection.resize(210, 40)
     radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection.toggle()
     radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection.move(90, 90)
     radiobox_choiсe_2_mainsection = l.QRadioButton('Девочка', l.root)
     radiobox_choiсe_2_mainsection.resize(200, 40)
     radiobox_choiсe_2_mainsection.move(90, 120)
     l.root.button_group = l.QButtonGroup()
     l.root.button_group.addButton(radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection, 1)
     l.root.button_group.addButton(radiobox_choiсe_2_mainsection, 2)
   ```
2. file2.py

   ```
   from PyQt5.QtCore import *
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
   from PyQt5.QtGui import *
   from itertools import groupby
   import sys
   import operation_function
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   root = QMainWindow()
   root.setFixedSize(400,400)
   root.setWindowTitle('')
   root.setWindowIcon(QIcon('image/font-main/icon.jpg'))
   operation_function.iii()
   root.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec())
   ```
3. main.py

   ```
   import l,operation_function
   ```

   или
4. main.py

   ```
   from PyQt5.QtCore import *
   from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
   from PyQt5.QtGui import *
   from itertools import groupby
   import sys
   import random
   import operation_function
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   root = QMainWindow()
   radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection = QRadioButton('Мальчик', root)
   radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection.resize(210, 40)
   radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection.toggle()
   radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection.move(90, 90)
   radiobox_choiсe_2_mainsection = QRadioButton('Девочка', root)
   radiobox_choiсe_2_mainsection.resize(200, 40)
   radiobox_choiсe_2_mainsection.move(90, 120)
   root.button_group = QButtonGroup()
   root.button_group.addButton(radiobox_choiсe_1_mainsection, 1)
   root.button_group.addButton(radiobox_choiсe_2_mainsection, 2)
   root.setFixedSize(400,400)
   root.setWindowTitle('')
   root.setWindowIcon(QIcon('image/font-main/icon.jpg'))
   root.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec())
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все зависит от того, что Вы пишите в первую очередь.

Как правило модули и отдельные файлы несут в семе отдельную смысловую нагрузку.

Это классы, либо полностью оттестированные и рабочие куски кода, наборы/заготовку функций, либо смысловые части кода (общение с БД, вычисления, работа с файлами, интерфейс пользователя, ...).

Подумайте имеет ли это смысл у Вас и решайте.

Comment: ну вот по примеру вот данного кода есть какой то смысл вот так делить?

Comment: Если это весь код, то не вижу смысла - он короткий, если же предполагается та же логика и код будет больше то можно и поделить. Не сказал про комментарии - они я считаю вообще всегда обязательны, Документируйте код - тем более что в питоне это очень круто сделано.

Comment: с комментариями согласнн хорошо сделано. Спасибо за ответ

Comment: А на работоспособность деление на модули влияет как то?

Comment: Нет. Программа либо работает либо не работает. Однако читабельность и как следствие удешевление поддержки кода модули увеличивают. Функции я советую выделять всегда (это как минимум удобно). Если вы имеете в виду производительность, то функции ее чуть чуть уменьшают, но это такие микроны. что Вы их не заметите

Answer (score 1):

Не должно возникать вопроса, как разбить неструктуированный блок кода на несколько файлов. Вместо этого допустимый вопрос выглядит как: стоит ли вынести коллекцию *функций*, *классов* в отдельный модуль.

То есть прежде чем думать о нескольких файлах, код должен подрасти,
чтобы была польза от разбиения его на отдельные функции, классы.

Полезная функция может иметь и одну строчку и тысячу. Признаки, что код в функцию можно вынести:

- осмысленное имя функции приходит на ум.

  Если `iii()` это лучшее имя, которое вы смогли придумать, то не стоит блок кода двигать
- цель функции легко описать в виде одного короткого предложения
  (первая строчка в docstring).

  Должна быть ясна цель функции и она не должна слишком много делать
- она используется в нескольких местах.

  Создание функции убирает ненужное дублирование кода.

Это только самые самые наброски: можно книгу написать (и они написаны)
о таких вещах, к примеру, книга «Совершенный код» Стив Макконнелла.

Код в вопросе крошечный (один блок), поэтому проблемы и выгода от
любого стилистического измения будут крошечными.

"Но с комментариями" — это ложное
противопоставление. Если комментарий нужен, его следует добавить вне
зависимости от того в одном модуле код или в нескольких.

В общем случае, удобней плоскими интерфейсами пользоваться (публичная функциональность не требует вложенные модули импортировать явно), при этом реализация может быть по нескольким внутренним модулям раскидана, пример: [asyncio](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Lib/asyncio).

Comment: Этот код просто так для примера не стоит лишней критики

Answer (score 1):

Код в отдельный модуль обязательно выносится в том случае, если уже происходит (или точно передполагется) вызов этого кода из разных других модулей. Очевидный пример - библиотечные модули.

В "просто большом" проекте удобно разделять по смыслу, чтобы разделить пространство переменных, просто чтобы файлы были умеренного размера.

Answer (score 1):

Один из способов разбиения заключается в поддержке нужной вам концепции. Например, если вы избрали MVC, то вероятнее всего в один модуль (содержащий M) пойдут объекты и отображение модели на базу данных, в другом (V) будут все функции и объекты, связанные с визуализацией а в (C, или в main) будет сама программа, отображающая взаимодействие объектов, суть жизни модели.

В любом случае нужно помнить, что разбиение на модули не может быть "правильным" или "неправильным". Компьютеру все равно как выполнять вашу программу - из одного модуля или собрав из разных файлов.

Разбиение на модули служит для удобства человека, который будет читать или модифицировать код.